# Angular - Update value of a slider from another slider

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

My usecase is as follows:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let ag of assetGroupsInScope" >
        <ion-col>
                  <ion-range
                  style="padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px;"
                  #sliderGroup
                  class="ion-no-padding"
                  [ngModel]="assetGroupCurrentValue(ag)"
                  #range="ngModel"
                  name="group-{{ ag }}"
                  min="0"
                  [max]="assetGroupMap.get(ag)"
                  pin
                  color="tertiary"
                >
                </ion-range>
            <ion-row *ngFor="let asset of assetGroupIds.get(ag)" class="ion-no-padding">
              <ion-col class="ion-no-padding">
                <div class="flex-container">
                  <div class="flex-card">
            
                      <ion-range
                        #sliderAsset
                        class="ion-no-padding"
                        [ngModel]="assetContributionMap.has(asset.id) ? assetContributionMap.get(asset.id) : 0"
                        #range="ngModel"
                        name="value-{{ asset.id }}"
                        min="0"
                        [max]="allAssetvalueMap.get(asset.id)"
                        pin
                        tick
                        color="tertiary"
                        (ionChange)="onChangeSlider(asset, sliderAsset)"
                      >
                      </ion-range>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

I have an array called assetGroupsInScope. For each assetGroup, I have one slider (Say master slider) for the overall value, and multiple sliders (say child sliders) for assets of the group.

What I want is when the user changes the master slider, code automatically updates the child sliders (some algorithm that ensures the sum of child sliders = master slider) and whenever the user changes any child slider, code automatically update the master slider.

Tried viewchild, elementref, renderer2 and other hacks but can't seem to figure out anything.
What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: please add  more details.

Comment: The core problem is I want to update all sliders to the same value when one slider is updated by the user (dragged to a value). And the list of sliders is dynamic, so cannot hardcode access using viewchild

Comment: why don't you use angular component variables use same variable in all of them and whenever you update the value of variable it will be updated on all sliders automatically

Comment: added more details to the question

Comment: when you make changes in your assetGroupsInScope whole component will be updated accordingly for example if let suppose you remove or add extra child into assetGroupsInScope it will automatically update the view according to new data

Comment: assetsGroupsInScope is input to this component, and I am not modifying it. The user can only modify the sliders. When I modify the sliders, even with two way data binding the view of the slider doesnt change.
Example - if my slider is at 45/100, and i change the two-way bound variable to 30, the slider still points to 45.